# Center two containers with absolute position within a div

Tags: css, html, center

Using CSS, I want to horizontally center two "boxes" I have within a div. The boxes are absolutely positioned.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/8/

How would I achieve this without using specific widths?

HTML:

```
<button id="change">Change</button>
<div id="total-wrap">
    <div id="hello-wrap" class="bunch">
        <div id="box"> 
            <p> Hello, this is text1 </p>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
            <p> Hello, this is text2 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="goodbye-wrap" class="bunch">
        <div id="box"> 
            <p> Goodbye, this is text1 </p>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
            <p> Goodbye, this is text2 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#total-wrap {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:500px;
}
#box {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:10px;
}
.bunch {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery to center those absolute positioned elements?

Comment: if you're going to be positioning them absolutely, you need specific widths

Comment: Btw: ids have to be unique use classes instead `<div id="box">` => `<div class="box">`

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with `left:0;` and `right:0` as they are absolutely positioned.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/p4sA3/19/

```
.bunch {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
        #total-wrap {
            border:1px solid #000;
            height:500px;
        }
        #box {
            display:inline-block;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:yellow;
            margin:10px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .bunch {
            text-align:center;
        }
```

Comment: "How would I achieve this **without using specific widths?**"

Comment: Just remove the width from my styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">Box1</div>
    <div id="right">Box2</div>
</div>
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 40px; 
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;  
}

#left, #right {
     background: yellow;
     display: inline-block;    
     padding: 20px;   
}
```

Comment: @BradleyMitchell o sorry i got it, my mistake. i will rectify that

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#box {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:10px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/11/

The thing is that as long the sum of the widths exceeds the container, the second div will be positioned beneath the first one

In this other demo I didn't use width: http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/13/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnWAn/2/)

```
keepCentered = function() { 
    $('#hello-wrap').css({'margin-left':($('#total-wrap').width()-$('#hello-wrap').width())/2});
    $('#goodbye-wrap').css({'margin-left':($('#total-wrap').width()-$('#goodbye-wrap').width())/2});
}
$(document).ready(keepCentered);
$(window).bind('resize', keepCentered);
```